# Signed int breaks parts of a larger bitfield

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

In trying to make a spatial grid of mesh lists for my game, I'm trying to make a unique hash based on coordinate data of the specific grid.  I'm trying to take my grid data: `WorldName world_name; uint8_t stage_index; short int pos_x; short int pos_y; short int pos_z;` and trying construct a unique `uint64_t hash_bitfield`.

My `uint64_t GenerateHash(...)` works great when my grid coordinates are positive.  However, when any are negative, I get an undesired effect:

```
world: 1        -->> 0000 0001
stage: 1        -->> 0000 0001
pos_x: 23       -->> 0000 0000 0001 0111
pos_y: -23      -->> 1111 1111 1110 1001
pos_z: 23       -->> 0000 0000 0001 0111

[ world ] [ stage ] [      pos_x      ] [      pos_y      ] [      pos_z      ]
--byte7-- --byte6-- --byte5-- --byte4-- --byte3-- --byte2-- --byte1-- --byte0--
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 1001 0000 0000 0001 0111 <-- what I get
0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0000 0001 0111 0000 0000 0001 0111 0000 0000 0001 0111 <-- when y is positive

What I expected:                        vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0000 0001 0111 1111 1111 1110 1001 0000 0000 0001 0111
```

Notice that pos_y being negative flips to 1 every other bit left of that byte.  nothing like this happens when all numbers are positive.  As you can see in this code below, I tried to manually flip the sign bits *after* copying the bits into a `uint64_t` (commented block).  It also did not work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

enum WorldName{    // These are collections of gameobj sectors
    WORLD_TYPE1,
    WORLD_TYPE2,
    WORLD_TYPE3,
    MAX_WORLDS
};

uint64_t GenerateHash( WorldName world_name, uint8_t stage_index, short int pos_x, short int pos_y, short int pos_z ){
    uint64_t world_name_t = world_name;
    uint64_t stage_index_t = stage_index;
    uint64_t pos_x_t = pos_x;
    uint64_t pos_y_t = pos_y;
    uint64_t pos_z_t = pos_z;

    // Try to flip the sign manually (it doesn't help)
    //uint64_t pos_x_t, pos_y_t, pos_z_t;
    //if( pos_x < 0 ){ pos_x_t = ~(uint64_t( abs( pos_x ) )) + 1; } else { pos_x_t = pos_x; }
    //if( pos_y < 0 ){ pos_y_t = ~(uint64_t( abs( pos_y ) )) + 1; } else { pos_y_t = pos_y; }
    //if( pos_z < 0 ){ pos_z_t = ~(uint64_t( abs( pos_z ) )) + 1; } else { pos_z_t = pos_z; }

    uint64_t hash_bitfield = 0x0;
    hash_bitfield |= world_name_t << (8 * 7);
    hash_bitfield |= stage_index_t << (8 * 6);
    hash_bitfield |= pos_x_t << (8 * 4);
    hash_bitfield |= pos_y_t << (8 * 2);
    hash_bitfield |= pos_z_t;

    return hash_bitfield;
}

void PrintBitString( std::string bitstr, std::string label="", bool print_ruler=true ){
    std::string buffer;
    int count = 0;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < bitstr.size(); i++ ){
        buffer += bitstr[i];
        count++;
        if( count >3 ){ buffer += ' ';  count = 0; }
    }

    if( print_ruler ){
        int num_of_bytes_to_draw = (bitstr.size() / 8);
        for( size_t k = num_of_bytes_to_draw; k > 0; --k ){
            cout << "--byte" << k - 1 << "-- ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << buffer << endl;
}

int main() {
    WorldName world_name = (WorldName) 1;    // 4B
    uint8_t stage_index = 1;     // 1B
    short int pos_x = 23;        // 2B
    short int pos_y = -23;       // 2B
    short int pos_z = 23;        // 2B

    std::bitset<8> world_name_bits( world_name );
    std::bitset<8> stage_index_bits( stage_index );
    std::bitset<16> pos_x_bits( pos_x );
    std::bitset<16> pos_y_bits( pos_y );
    std::bitset<16> pos_z_bits( pos_z );
    cout << "world: " << world_name << "\t-->> " << world_name_bits << endl;
    cout << "stage: " << (int)stage_index << "\t-->> " << stage_index_bits << endl;
    cout << "pos_x: " << pos_x << "\t-->> " << pos_x_bits << endl;
    cout << "pos_y: " << pos_y << "\t-->> " << pos_y_bits << endl;
    cout << "pos_z: " << pos_z << "\t-->> " << pos_z_bits << endl << endl;

    uint64_t my_hash = GenerateHash( world_name, stage_index, pos_x, pos_y, pos_z );
    uint64_t my_hash_abs = GenerateHash( world_name, stage_index, pos_x, abs(pos_y), pos_z );

    cout << "[ world ] [ stage ] [      pos_x      ] [      pos_y      ] [      pos_z      ]" << endl;
    std::bitset<64> bits( my_hash );
    std::bitset<64> bits_abs( my_hash_abs );
    PrintBitString( bits.to_string() );
    PrintBitString( bits_abs.to_string(),"",false );
    cout << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

How can I get a uint64_t that looks like my [expected] bitfield, above (where pos_y's bitfield affects only those 16 bits of byte2 and byte3)?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cast the `pos_x` etc variables to `unsigned short` before assigning them to `pos_x_t`

```
uint_64_t pos_x_t = (unsigned short) pos_x;
```

Or you can mask the value

```
uint_64_t pos_x_t = uint_64_t(pos_x) & 0xFFFF;
```

Or use an appropriate mask when storing it in `hash_bitfield`

```
hash_bitfield |= (pos_x_t & 0xFFFF) << (8 * 4);
```

The masking could also be done after the shift, but then you'd need to use a shifted version of the mask.

Comment: by `unsigned short` you mean `uint16_t`

Comment: This did the trick.  It's sosimple I'm ashamed I didn't think of it.  Thanks.
    uint64_t pos_x_t = uint16_t( pos_x );
    uint64_t pos_y_t = uint16_t( pos_y );
    uint64_t pos_z_t = uint16_t( pos_z );